# Webcam problems on Centos 6.6

Tags: linux, centos, xorg, webcam

I've been unable to get a few different webcams working on CentOS 6.6. (Logitech C270 & Creative Live! Cam Sync HD)

I think it's related udev but unsure. The following are my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/messages`. Does it think it's a keyboard?

#### /var/log/Xorg.0.log (on inserting & removing both cams)

```
[   772.788] (II) config/hal: Adding input device Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770
[   772.788] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770'
[   772.788] (**) Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770: always reports core events
[   772.788] (**) evdev: Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770: Device: "/dev/input/event19"
[   772.796] (--) evdev: Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770: Vendor 0x41e Product 0x4095
[   772.796] (--) evdev: Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770: Found keys
[   772.796] (II) evdev: Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770: Configuring as keyboard
[   772.796] (**) Option "config_info" "hal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_41e_4095_2014062000244_if0_logicaldev_input"
[   772.796] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[   772.796] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   772.796] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105+inet"
[   772.796] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   772.796] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[   772.796] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   777.733] (II) config/hal: removing device Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770
[   777.740] (II) evdev: Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770: Close
[   777.740] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
###########################################
[   817.391] (II) config/hal: Adding input device UVC Camera (046d:0825)
[   817.391] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'UVC Camera (046d:0825)'
[   817.391] (**) UVC Camera (046d:0825): always reports core events
[   817.391] (**) evdev: UVC Camera (046d:0825): Device: "/dev/input/event19"
[   817.399] (--) evdev: UVC Camera (046d:0825): Vendor 0x46d Product 0x825
[   817.399] (--) evdev: UVC Camera (046d:0825): Found keys
[   817.399] (II) evdev: UVC Camera (046d:0825): Configuring as keyboard
[   817.399] (**) Option "config_info" "hal:/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_46d_825_226045A0_if0_logicaldev_input"
[   817.399] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "UVC Camera (046d:0825)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[   817.399] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   817.399] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105+inet"
[   817.399] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   817.399] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[   817.399] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   828.720] (II) config/hal: removing device UVC Camera (046d:0825)
[   828.727] (II) evdev: UVC Camera (046d:0825): Close
[   828.727] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
```

#### /var/log/Xorg.0.log (on inserting & removing both cams)

```
Jan 24 15:37:02 machina kernel: usb 2-5: new high speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
Jan 24 15:37:02 machina kernel: usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=041e, idProduct=4095
Jan 24 15:37:02 machina kernel: usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
Jan 24 15:37:02 machina kernel: usb 2-5: Product: Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770
Jan 24 15:37:02 machina kernel: usb 2-5: Manufacturer: Creative Technology Ltd.
Jan 24 15:37:02 machina kernel: usb 2-5: SerialNumber: 2014062000244
Jan 24 15:37:02 machina kernel: usb 2-5: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Jan 24 15:37:02 machina kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770 (041e:4095)
Jan 24 15:37:02 machina kernel: input: Live! Cam Sync HD VF0770 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0/input/input27
Jan 24 15:37:02 machina rtkit-daemon[4500]: Sucessfully made thread 8825 of process 4790 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1003' RT at priority 5.
Jan 24 15:37:20 machina kernel: usb 2-5: USB disconnect, device number 9
###########################################
Jan 24 15:38:11 machina kernel: usb 2-5: new high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
Jan 24 15:38:11 machina kernel: usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0825
Jan 24 15:38:11 machina kernel: usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=2
Jan 24 15:38:11 machina kernel: usb 2-5: SerialNumber: 226045A0
Jan 24 15:38:11 machina kernel: usb 2-5: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Jan 24 15:38:11 machina kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
Jan 24 15:38:11 machina kernel: input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0/input/input28
Jan 24 15:38:12 machina kernel: 10:3:2: cannot set freq 24000 to ep 0x86
Jan 24 15:38:13 machina rtkit-daemon[4500]: Sucessfully made thread 9026 of process 4790 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1003' RT at priority 5.
Jan 24 15:38:26 machina kernel: usb 2-5: USB disconnect, device number 10
```

Please help! What am I missing?

#### output of dmesg|tail after inserting

```
usb 2-6: new high speed USB device number 14 using ehci_hcd
usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0825
usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=2
usb 2-6: SerialNumber: 226045A0
usb 2-6: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x80 by module parameter for testing purpose.
uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/input/input37
14:3:1: cannot set freq 16000 to ep 0x86
```

#### output of cheese

```
libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!
libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!
libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device
```

#### output of ucview

```
libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!
libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!
libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!
libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!
libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!
libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!

** (ucview:2199): WARNING **: Failed to set property: White Balance Temperature


** (ucview:2199): WARNING **: Failed to set property: Exposure (Absolute)

libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!
libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!
libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!
libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!

(ucview:2199): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_set_string: assertion `val != NULL' failed
search module path: /home/rmoggach/.ucview/plugins
search module path: /usr/lib64/ucview/plugins
libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device

** (ucview:2199): WARNING **: Failed to start video capture
```

#### output of camorama

```
libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!
libv4lconvert: warning more framesizes then I can handle!

(camorama:3381): Gtk-WARNING **: GtkSpinButton: setting an adjustment with non-zero page size is deprecated
libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device
libv4l2: error reading: Invalid argument
```

#### output of dmesg after reboot (with camera connected)

After reboot machine is extremely slow and X is messed up. Unplugging fixes the slowness.

```
usb 2-2: reset high speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
snd-usb-audio 2-2:1.2: no reset_resume for driver snd-usb-audio?
snd-usb-audio 2-2:1.3: no reset_resume for driver snd-usb-audio?
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
2:3:4: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x86
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug with webcams in CentOS 6.6 and reported as Bugzilla #1158988 with Red Hat.

It has been fixed in the plus kernel:

http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=7815

Comment: I'm using CentOS6.6 and having the same problem. How can I patch my CentOS6.6 kernel? I read http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source but following it doesn't lead to getting the source .c and .h files.

Answer (score 0):

According to the CentOS bug report 7815 referenced by mogga, the bug has already been fixed in later kernels (as of 2.6.32-504.1.3.el6). If you have not done so, you should update the kernel to the latest CentOS-6 kernel. That should solve the issue.

Comment: How about a link to the bug report and the relevant information from said report?